# magento product attribute return NULL after a getChildHtml call

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9.2.2,
I have created a childhtml that takes care of reviews, it looks like:

```
    <catalog_product_view translate="label">
     <reference name="product.info">

       <block type="review/product_view_list" name="productinfo.reviewinfo" as="hs_review" template="catalog\product\hs_review.phtml"></block>

      </reference> 
    </catalog_product_view>
```

`hs_reviw.ptml`:

```
    <?php  $ratingSummary =Mage::getModel('rating/rating')->getEntitySummary($_p->getId()); ?>

      <div class="review-container">
         <?php if ($ratingSummary) { ?>
              <div class="w ratting">
                  <div class="rating-value" style="width: <?php 
                   echo $ratingSummary->getSum() / $ratingSummary->getCount(); ?>%"></div>
              </div>

            <div class="reviw-count w">
             <span><?php echo $ratingSummary->getCount() ?> Reviews</span>
            </div>

        <?php } ?>

         <div class="review-add w">
             <a href="<?php  echo  Mage::getUrl('review/product/list',
               array('id'=> $this->getProduct()->getId(),
                      'category'  => $this->getProduct()->getCategoryId()
               )); ?>">Write a Review</a>
         </div>

     </div>
```

now the strange thing happens in view.ptml
when i use

```
<?php var_dump( $_product->getShortDescription()); ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hs_review')?>
```

it dumps product short description and reviews but when I use

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('hs_review')?>
<?php var_dump( $_product->getShortDescription()); ?>
```

review works perfectly but product short description return Null